# Silverlight unit testing. Error while running tests

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, nunit, typemock

I'm using VS2010. Silverlight 4, NUnit 2.5.5, and TypeMock
TypemockIsolatorSetup6.0.3.619.msi

In the test project MVVM is implemented, PeopleViewModel is a ViewModel which I want to test.

Please advise if you use other products for unit testing of MVVM Silverlight. Or please help to win this TypeMock. TIA

This is the code of the test:

```
[Test]
[SilverlightUnitTest] 
public void SomeTestAgainstSilverlight()
{
    PeopleViewModel o = new PeopleViewModel();
    var res = o.People;

    Assert.AreEqual(15, res.Count());
}
```

While running the test in ReSharper i get the following error:

```
TestA.SomeTestAgainstSilverlight : Failed******************************************
*Loading Silverlight Isolation Aspects...*
******************************************

 TEST RESULTS:
---------------------------------------------

    System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'hv TypeMock.ArrangeActAssert.Isolate.a(System.Delegate)'.
    at a4.a(ref Delegate A_0)
    at a4.a(Boolean A_0)
    at il.b()
    at CThru.Silverlight.SilverlightUnitTestAttribute.Init()
    at CThru.Silverlight.SilverlightUnitTestAttribute.Execute()
    at TypeMock.MockManager.a(String A_0, String A_1, Object A_2, Object A_3, Boolean A_4, Object[] A_5)
    at TypeMock.InternalMockManager.getReturn(Object that, String typeName, String methodName, Object methodParameters, Boolean isInjected)
    at Tests.TestA.SomeTestAgainstSilverlight() in TestA.cs: line 21
```

While running test in NUnit i get:

```
Tests.TestA.SomeTestAgainstSilverlight:
System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'agcore': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_GetCurrentNative(IntPtr context, IntPtr& obj)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_GetCurrent(IntPtr& pApp)
at System.Windows.Application.get_Current()
at ViewModelExample.ViewModel.ViewModelBase.get_IsDesignTime() in C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\ViewModelExample\ViewModelExample\ViewModel\ViewModelBase.cs:line 20
at ViewModelExample.ViewModel.PeopleViewModel..ctor(IServiceAgent serviceAgent) in C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\ViewModelExample\ViewModelExample\ViewModel\PeopleViewModel.cs:line 28
at ViewModelExample.ViewModel.PeopleViewModel..ctor() in C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\ViewModelExample\ViewModelExample\ViewModel\PeopleViewModel.cs:line 24
at Tests.TestA.SomeTestAgainstSilverlight() in C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\ViewModelExample\Tests\TestA.cs:line 22
```

**UPDATE: I'm not following the question. I've switched to other tools.**

Comment: I assume this is a conflict between SL and .NET 4.0 core dlls.

You can try to solve this by configuring system level dll reference hintpaths from project files and using 'extern alias'.

Answer (score 0):

This message looks like a mismatched files issue. Try creating a new test project from scratch.

Start by adding references to `Typemock.dll` and `Typemock.ArrangeActAssert.dll`. From the CThru directory add both `CThru.dll` and `CThru.Silverlight.dll`.

Add a reference to `System.Windows` (located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Windows.dll`).

Try creating a new test method, and decorate it with `SilverlightUnitTest` attribute:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using CThru.Silverlight;

[TestFixture]
public class SilverlightTest
{
    [Test, SilverlightUnitTest]
    public void EmptyTest()
    {

    }
}
```

Run this empty test. If you're still having the problem you described, please contact `support at typemock.com` for further assistance.